# Does a PWA need to be installed to be used offline?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA served e.g. at https://my-pwa.com. Users may "install" this PWA by adding it to their homescreen. The PWA is then available offline as it uses a service worker.

My question is if the "add to homescreen" step is necessary for the app to work offline or if it could be used offline without "add to homescreen"?

Comment: Don't think so. AFAIK the Service Worker caches the entire application rightaway

Comment: @Pieterjan, I find your answer a bit contradicting. If the service worker caches the entire application right away, then the application should be available offline, right? Or do you mean that the service worker will only cache the application _after_ being installed (as in, added to homescreen)?

Comment: Well I tried with Firefox and I seemingly don't need to install my own pwa in order to use it offline.

Comment: I just ran a similar test using app.starbucks.com and had the same results. @Pieterjan I would accept an answer stating what you just did.

Comment: And I based my response on the fact that I've been struggling in the past with new pwa versions not being shown after I deployed a new version to the server. Then too the pwa wasn't installed, but the older version of my website kept popping up, since it was cached+served by the Service Worker ([solution](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.component.ts#L86-L101) + increment the [version](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/ngsw-config.json#L4) field on each deploy)

Comment: I updated the question to hopefully be more clear. "Well I tried with Firefox and I seemingly don't need to install my own pwa in order to use it offline." <- this is the answer I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on testing performed by myself and [@Pieterjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8941307/pieterjan) it turns out that PWAs are indeed accessible offline even when not explicitly added to the user's homescreen.

I.e. a user visiting `https://my-pwa.com` can later re-visit `https://my-pwa.com` in the same browser without an internet connection. No "add to homescreen" required.

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement for anyone to install or add a PWA to the homescreen to make offline available.
Like others have stated, the service worker handles HTTPS requests. If you have assets cached locally you can make your application work offline.
Now you will need to manage how you handle offline and this can lead to a reasonably complex application to handle synchronizing requests and what you make available while offline.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear.

But I assume you intend to use your PWA locally without a WiFi-connection.

And yes that is possible. You actually can also work on it without being connected to the internet if you just have your IDE open and all the modules installed.

And that's the point. I assume you use a framework like ionic. Let's say I'd clone your project from git and have the files stored locally:

1. I would open the project in my IDE.
2. Most modern IDEs scan the package.json. When you install a module via npm while developing it will be added as a dependancy. They ask you if you want to install the modules. Alternatively you can type npm install and it will get the modules from the internet.
3. If you have extra dependencies that need to be installed, you'd have to do so. (not via npm i)
4. You can now run your project locally without a WiFi connection AS LONG as the PWA itself doesn't need WiFi.

Depending on your framework you can now run the app (with Angular by ng serve or ng build for ionic with ionic --serve etc). You could also run a server locally and let them communicate together. No WiFi needed.

Installing is not trivial and requires at least some knowledge about using IDEs. A simple: "Add to homescreen" would not help. I think the website is cached on so works offline. If you'd clear that cache the website should break.

Comment: The question is about a PWA served e.g. at `https://my-pwa.com`. Users may "install" this PWA by adding it to their homescreen. The PWA is then available offline as it uses a service worker. My question is if the app is still available offline if the users skip the "add to homescreen" step.